# How to create eIDAS certificate with QWAC and QSealC profiles (PSD2 specific attributes) for testing

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, psd2

I want to create a eIDAS certificate with QWAC and QSealC profiles with PSD2 specific attributes as mentioned in the doc.
Please help me, this is just for testing purposes.

https://docbox.etsi.org/ESI/Open/Latest_Drafts/ts_119495v000003_for-public-review.pdf

Comment: we will soon offer test QWAC and QSeal certificates issued according to the latest PSD2 RTS spec.

Comment: Can we get a test QWAC and QSeal certificates now?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same requirement months ago, and I wrote a eIDAS test certificate generator compliant psd2. I followed the ASN.1 Declaration giving by the "ts_119495v000003_for-public-review.pdf" document.

here is the link to generate [eIDAS test certificate generator](http://tppserver.cloud.adorsys.de/swagger-ui.html#!/certificate-ctrl/addUsingPOST)

And then here [xs2a open srce](https://github.com/adorsys/xs2a) we have write some certificate extractor, to extract psd2 attributes and roles from the generated certificate.

Comment: The link to the certificate generator is dead.

Answer (score 4):

For me the simplest option was to use OpenSSL command line utility:

```
openssl req -new -config qwac.conf -keyout qwac.key -out qwac.csr && openssl x509 -req -in qwac.csr -signkey qwac.key -out qwac.crt
```

qwac.conf is [openssl config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/config.html) where you have to set PSD2 specific fields as described [here](https://enablebanking.com/blog/2020/01/13/how-to-generate-eidas-certificate/). Configs for QWAC and QSealC can be exactly the same, just need to run command twice.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1d already has OID 2.5.4.97 being defined. Instead of defining this OID as custom in `[ dn ]` section use name "organizationIdentifier"

Answer (score 3):

I would like to extend @guymoyo's answer with clearer instruction.
Xs2a (https://github.com/adorsys/xs2a) repository provides a docker image for Xs2a certificate generator:
https://hub.docker.com/r/adorsys/xs2a-certificate-generator

So to generate your own TPP certificate all you need to do:

1. Run docker image

```
docker run -p 8092:8092 adorsys/xs2a-certificate-generator
```

2. Open your browser and navigate to `Swagger UI` http://localhost:8092/swagger-ui.html
3. Or directly to [createCertUsingPOST Swagger operation](http://localhost:8092/swagger-ui.html#/certificate-controller/createCertUsingPOST)
4. Click on `Try it out` of `createCertUsingPOST`
5. Generated certificate will appear in the endpoint response

Answer (score 1):

I too created a certificate generator.

Based on [ts_119495v010302p.pdf](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/119400_119499/119495/01.03.02_60/ts_119495v010302p.pdf)

https://github.com/payoneer/Psd2CertificateGenerator

Used .Net Core 3.1

Feel free to comment, suggest, report issues and create pull requests.

Comment: 404 repo does not exists

Comment: Here you go
https://github.com/elisherer/Psd2CertificateGenerator